# How to remove commits by a foreign contributor when squashing commits?

Tags: git

I want to squash the last 25 commits into one commit, so I did this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~25
git commit -m "main refactor"
```

I have squashed the commits and added to one commit but I wanted it to remove or hide all contributions from a foreign contributor.

All foreign contribution have been joined into one commit as a commit from branch owner but it still keeps record of commits made by foreign contributor. How can I remove or hide the commits from the contributor?

By the way, I merged the contributor's commit some time ago.

Comment: Did it do what you expected it to do?

Comment: I cant tell because I tried to push and it showed few changes not something I recognized , I will update, my question with result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this on a branch with all 25 non-squashed commits:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~25
```

In the text file that pops up, change `pick` to `squash` for the commits you want to be squashed, and change `pick` to `drop` for the commits by another contributor that you don’t want to keep. Then save and close the text file to do those listed steps.

Note that this will modify the branch you are on. If you still want to be able to access the 25 non-squashed commits after this, create a backup branch first.